# How can I create propirty file for sql queries in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, properties

I have some sql queries in my java code. Now I want to move it to property file. But I want create another property file for storing my sql queries. I have tried create:

```
sample.properties
```

And write in this file:

```
sql.getCallDetail = //sql query
```

Then in java class:

```
PropertySource(value = "sample.properties")
public class ImeiBuilderDefault implements ImeiBuilder {

@Value("${sql.getCallDetail}")
    private String getCallDetail;
```

But my project not build.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below

```
 ** sql.properties **

queries.ex1="select * from ex1"
queries.ex2="select * from ex2"

@PropertySource(value="classpath:sql.properties")
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class SqlQueries {

    private Map<String,String> queries;
//getters and setters
}

**TEST CLASS **

@Component
public class TestSQLQueries {

    @Autowired
    private SqlQueries queries;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

        queries.getQueries().entrySet().stream().forEach(entry->{
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue());
        });
    }

}
```

please find the demo project https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/Spring-Task-Sample/tree/master/Spring-SQLQueries-props